# Compare Columns Where One is Similar to Part of Another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a Select statement where I can see if one column is like part of another.

```
tblNames 
ID    FullName                   FirstName
1     Mr. John Doe, CEO          John
2     Mr. Jake Doe, Exec        Jake
3     Mrs. Betty Smith, Chair     Jill
```

The query should return:

```
3 | Mrs.Betty Smith, Chair | Jill
```

However mine just returns every row in the table:

```
SELECT ID, FullName, FirstName
FROM tblNames
WHERE '%' + FirstName + '%' not like Fullname
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Question is asking "like", but accepted answer is about "not like"

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Reverse the where, to something like this:

```
Fullname not like '%' + FirstName + '%'
```

Comment: It seems DB2 has issues with like operator with fields in the where condition

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `col1` NOT LIKE CONCAT('%', `col2`, '%')
```

Found it here:
http://www.edmondscommerce.co.uk/mysql/compare-two-columns-in-mysql/

Somehow it only worked correctly with the concat-function (?).

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! Like you this is the only one that worked in my case. Did you happen to discover why?

Comment: nice one, thanks for taking the time to post it

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblNames
WHERE  ISNULL( CHARINDEX (FirstName , FullName),0) = 0
```

The `CHARINDEX` will be faster (more performant) than a `LIKE` clause, as it doesn't have to take wildcards into account. The sample data above with small numbers of rows won't show a performance benefit, but when in the millions of rows, `CHARINDEX` would perform better.

Comment: +1. From what I hear, even `PATINDEX()` is faster than `LIKE`. Anyway, in this case `CHARINDEX()` is absolutely applicable and the best choice.

Answer (score 3):

Switch the arguments to `LIKE` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT ID, FullName, FirstName
FROM tblNames
WHERE Fullname not like '%' + FirstName + '%'
```

The wildcard must be the second argument.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle expects number when + is used. For string, please use the samle below :

```
SELECT ID, FullName, FirstName
FROM tblNames
WHERE FullName like '%' || FirstName||'%'
```

To compare one column of a table to a column of another table, please do the following

```
select a.*,table_2_col_1, table_2_col_2 from (select table_1_col_1, table_1_col_2 from table_1 where
)  a, table_2 where   table_1_col_1 like '%' || table_2_col_1 ||'%'
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks OK, except you probably want to switch the order around in your where:

```
WHERE Fullname not like '%' + FirstName + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses also would have fixed the issue.

```
SELECT ID, FullName, FirstName
FROM tblNames
WHERE ('%' + FirstName + '%') not like Fullname
```

Answer (score 0):

With Google BigQuery:

```
Fullname NOT LIKE ('%' || FirstName || '%')
```