# How to compare an attribute value in one column with every one in anther column in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-columns

I am new to mysql. 
And I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700550/compare-columns-where-one-is-similar-to-part-of-another) and several others on stackoverflow. They all suggest using LIKE but I still cannot get the right result. I wonder if the problem is caused by different rows containing the information.

Suppose I have a talbe `CD` like this:

```
artist        album
Prince        Purple Rain
Adam          Prince Charming
```

And I want to select artist `Prince` because it appears in both artist and album, I have tried using: `SELECT artist from CD WHERE album LIKE CONCAT('%', artist, '%')`

But it kept returning 0 result, and I don't understand why it does not work, anyone can help me?

edit: More information on 'TABLE CD':

```
artist        album
Prince        Purple Rain
Adam          Prince Charming
James         Apple
Furious       Banana
Beatles       Let It Be
It            Come
```

And it should return artist `Prince`,`It`

Comment: I think you should pass a PHP variable into the query: `"SELECT ... WHERE album LIKE '%" . $connection->escape($artist) . "%'"`. But the description is unclear. You might have meant some kind of JOIN.

Comment: what output you want pls provide example.

Comment: The output should be the artist `Prince`, since it is in both `artist` column and `album` column

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov Can you explain more about PHP variable and tell where you do not understand so I can provide more information

Comment: @DexD.Hunter, I mean you most likely accept the search string from the user, or as a function argument, - some kind of PHP variable. It is common to pass dynamic values into SQL queries. Then you probably want something like `$sql = sprintf('... WHERE artist like "%1$s" OR album like "%$1s"', $artist_escaped);`. Currently you are trying to build a LIKE expression as `concat('%', album, '%')` . But `album` refers to each `album` value in the table

Comment: Ok, I will delete the other post. @ypercubeᵀᴹ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you, try this

```
SELECT artist FROM yourTable WHERE (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(album) FROM yourTable) LIKE CONCAT('%',artist,'%');
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/acd44d/13)

***GROUP_CONCAT***

This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL values from a group (i.e from the result of your query). It returns NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

For more details about `GROUP_CONCAT` see this [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and [this](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/22/the-power-of-mysql-group_concat/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare collections of records against collections of other records, then a simple `LIKE` comparison in the `WHERE` clause won't suffice.  Instead, you will have to do some sort of aggregation across records.  The following query will return true if `'Prince'` appears one or more times in both the `artist` and `album` columns.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM yourTable
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN artist LIKE '%Prince%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
           SUM(CASE WHEN album  LIKE '%Prince%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
) THEN "True" ELSE "False" END
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. But what if there are other artist named other than 'Prince'?

Comment: Hi, I added some more cases for clarification

Comment: @DexD.Hunter You might need to use full text search/dynamic SQL if you want to return a list of common strings.

Comment: So LIKE only compares columns in the same row?

Comment: Not `LIKE` per se.  If you use a `WHERE` clause, then you are comparing _columns_ in a single _record_.  Your requirement needs some kind of aggregation of records.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a left join with the same table and use your like condition to join them.

```
SELECT
   t1.artist,
   t2.album
FROM
   artists t1 
   left join
      artists t2 
      on t2.album LIKE concat('%', t1.artist, '%') 
where
   t2.album is not NULL 
group by
   t1.artist
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e416b/1)