# Search varchar column on one table based on value in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following tables in SQL Server:

**Table 1**

```
id    bigint 
desc  nvarchar(255)
```

**Table 2**

```
id    bigint
email nvarchar(25)
```

I want to create a query that will search Table 1's desc column for a match on Table 2's email column.

For example, the following should return a match:

```
Table 1 desc = 'This is a test of test@gmail.com query to return results'.

Table 2 email = 'test@gmail.com'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: join ... but have you tried something yet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare Columns Where One is Similar to Part of Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700550/compare-columns-where-one-is-similar-to-part-of-another)

Answer (score 0):

You might require to join both the tables and do like as below:

```
  select * from #table1 t1 inner join #table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
  and t1.descr like '%' + t2.email + '%'
```