# display ALL values which are a part of another (sql server)

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this one

t1

```
ID  Full Name           FirstName    Name       Birthdate
1   Marc Lussier           
2   Stacy Carter           
4                       marc         Lussier    1900-01-01
5                        Stacy       Carter     2020-03-05
6  Keven Devaux         Keven        Devaux     2021-05-09
```

In my table there are mistakes. Sometimes the field `Name`  and `FirstName` are blank for 1 iD while the `FullName` is not.

The problem is, this same person would be duplicate with another iD but the fullName will be blank and you would find the name and first name corresponding to the full name.

First, i thought i would do a concat(name and firstname) and look when they are equal. But sometimes in the name or first name there are padding.

So based on my researches i wrote a query based on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700550/compare-columns-where-one-is-similar-to-part-of-another) :

```
SELECT ID, FullName, FirstName, Name, Birthdate
   FROM tblNames
   WHERE Fullname like '%' + FirstName + '%' or Fullname like '%' + Name + '%'
```

The query return :

```
    ID    Full Name                  FirstName      Name       Birthdate
    1     Marc Lussier           
    2     Stacy Carter
```

But i want the query to return :

```
ID    Full Name                  FirstName      Name       Birthdate
1     Marc Lussier           
2     Stacy Carter           
4                               marc          Lussier     1900-01-01
5                               Stacy         Carter      2020-03-05
```

Need your help :(

Comment: You are trying to get multiple records from the same table based on other records in that table.  Thus, you'll have better luck with a self-join than with just a where.  That's because the where is essentially doing single-record filtering, where you want cross-record filtering.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. Actually I also tried to create 2 temporary tables #t1 and #t2 wich contains (idclient,fullname,firstname,name,birthdate) both and made a inner join between them on **t1.idClient=t2.idClient where t1.Fullname like '%' + t2.FirstName + '%' or t1.Fullname like '%' + t2.Name + '%'**. The result where the same. What can i use to do the cross-record filtering ?

Comment: What are you trying to get? Rows where `full name` or `name` is blank?

Comment: Rows with fullName not blank and Name/FirstName Blank and rows with full name blank while name/firstname not blank.

Comment: Not to take you off the current line of attempts but did you try trimming the columns before concatenating and comparing?

Comment: yes i tried it. I think my problem is in the matching but i don't know how to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. `Where` clause excludes all rows where `Full Name`, `FirstName`, `Name` is not blank

```
select
    *
from
    myTable
where
    not (
            isnull(len([Full Name]), 0) > 0 
            and isnull(len(FirstName), 0) > 0 
            and isnull(len(Name), 0) > 0
        )
```

Edit

```
select
    *
from
    myTable a
where
    exists (
        select 1
        from myTable b
        where
            a.id <> b.id
            and replace(a.FullName, ' ', '') = replace(b.FirstName + b.Name, ' ', '')
    )
```

Comment: This would miss if they have values but fail to match.

Comment: Match what? From OPs comment he wants to show rows where `Rows with fullName not blank and Name/FirstName Blank and rows with full name blank while name/firstname not blank`

Comment: Hi thanks but it doesnt work. I would like the result to show me different cases where customers A got double identities with his name and first name correctly entered in the fields FirstName and Name but missing in FullName and this same guy A has his name entered only on FullName but nothing on Name/FirstName.

Comment: I am just getting that from the title.  It is not clear.

Comment: @It'smeAndYou That requirement is so not clear in your question or code you tried.  Fix the question.  Have more test cases.

Comment: @uzi it worked perfectly ! It worked better than the solution i've found (i'll post in 1minute) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try - you should not be getting all rows even with the old query

```
declare @t table (id int, name varchar(20), fname varchar(20), lname varchar(20));
insert into @t 
values (1, ' Marc Lussier', null, null)           
     , (2, ' Stacy Carter',  null, null)          
     , (4, null, 'marc', 'Lussier')  
     , (5, null, ' Stacy', 'Carter')   
     , (6, 'Keven Devaux', 'Keven', 'Devaux')
     , (7, 'Keven Devaux', ' Ceven', 'Devaux');

select * 
from @t t 
where name is null or fname is null or lname is null 
   or LTRIM(rtrim(name)) <> (LTRIM(rtrim(fname)) + ' ' + LTRIM(rtrim(lname)))
```

Comment: Hi ! When i add this query, it returns me all the rows of my table as if i did nothing

Comment: That is odd.  I will try and test.

Comment: i don't know why but this method it doesn't work. I just return all my data without filtering them

Comment: I cannot believe your server has different results than mine.  I give up.

Answer (score 0):

Hi everyone thanks for your help and suggestions.It helped me to finally find a solution,  i used a concat and a double select:

```
SELECT x.ID, x.FullName, X.FirstName, x.Name, x.ConcatNamex.Birthdate
from Tb1  
    (SELECT ID, FullName, FirstName, Name, concat((ltrim(rtrim(FirstName),'', (ltrim(rtrim(Name)) as ConcatName, Birthdate
   FROM tblNames ) X

  on x.ConcatName = tb1.NomCompagnie
```

And it worked. But @uzi query worked too with more filters in the where clause.

Thanks guys :)